# Dynamic object is not getting inserted

Tags: apex, batch, dynamic-apex, dynamic-binding

I want to insert dynamic object with dynamic fields and value. I have written below code in execute method and i am getting "Attempt to de-reference a null object" error and not finding where I am wrong.
I have dynamic query which is returning a list of records of different objects. I want to insert one record for each retrieved record. Newly created record will have the same field value as the old retrieved record. eg. old retrieved opportunity record's Name = 'xyz', probability = 60. i want to insert an opportunity with Name = 'xyz', probability = 60. Like this i have records from different standard and custom objects with different fields in each object record. and i want to insert a new record for each with the corresponding field and value. I do not want deep clone, I want with dynamic fields selected by users and all mandatory fields which I have extracted already in my query.

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> objList) { 

    Schema.SObjectType sObjectType = objList.getSObjectType();
    if (sObjectType != null){
        String listType = 'List<' + sObjectType + '>';
        List<SObject> castRecords = (List<SObject>)Type.forName(listType).newInstance();
        List<String> fields = new List<String>(sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
       // Map<SObjectField, Object> fields = new Map<SObjectField, Object>();
        Map<String,String> mapObj = new Map<String,String>();
        for(SObject obj : objList) {
            for (string field : fields) {
                Object value = obj .get(field);
                if(value != null){
                    string sObjectName = '\''+ sObjectType+ '\'' ;
                    sObject newObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectName).newSObject(); 
                    newObj.put(String.valueOf(field), String.valueOf(value));
                    castRecords.add(newObj);
                }
            }
            List<sObject> objects = new List<sObject>();
            objects.addAll((List<sObject>)(castRecords));
            insert objects; 
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Your inner `for loop` is iterating over a `keySet()` of an empty map. Aside from this, it is difficult to understand what field values you are looking to assign to the dynamic `SObject`. I recommend you improve your question by clearly defining your needs. (fyi you can use `System.debug()` to understand your code rather than saying it completed successfully)

Comment: @TSmith, Thanks for notifying me the empty map. I have modified the code now and getting  "Attempt to de-reference a null object" error and not finding where I am wrong.

Comment: @TSmith, I have dynamic query which is returning a list of records of different objects.
I want to insert one record for each retrieved record.
Newly created record will have the same field value as the old retrieved record.
eg. old retrieved opportunity record's Name = 'xyz', probability = 60. 
i want to insert an opportunity with Name = 'xyz', probability = 60.
Like this i have records from different standard and custom objects with different fields in each object record.
and i want to insert a new record for each with the corresponding field and value.

Comment: What's the main use case?  Give us some background and we can better guide you.  Also, the line of code with `string sObjectName = '\''+ sObjectType+ '\'' ;` will error out - there's no need to enclose the sObjectType string with apostrophes

Comment: why not use `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap` as a shortcut for the fields retrieved in the start method?